# QLineEdit InputMask and blanks inserted

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I have a `QLineEdit` with an `InputMask` set to `">AAAA90"`, that is, I expect the text to consists of exactly 4 uppercase Ascii letters and between 1-2 digits. If the user types "AA1" however, the `QLineEdit` will show `AA  1`, namely it will insert two blanks and print the "1" which is permitted in the 5th position. I would rather want a behavior like with illegal characters at any position, namely if the user types "AA%" then the cursor stays at the third position and does not print the "%" character.

Is this possible in QT5?

Comment: So, are spaces allowed in the first four letters?

Comment: This is absolutely possible, have a look at [`QValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Mike for the tip on QValidator, I ended up hooking a validator like

```
 QRegExp rgx("[a-zA-Z]{4}\\d{1,2}");
 QValidator *comValidator = new QRegExpValidator (rgx, this);
 comLineEdit->setValidator(comValidator);
```

And hooking `textEdited` with:

```
void MainWindow::comTextEdited(const QString &arg1)
{
  qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(sender())->setText(arg1.toUpper());
}
```

To force the first 4 characters to uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Input Masks don't *insert* blank spaces in the returned text (i.e. return value of `QLineEdit::text()` method), although blank spaces are inserted in GUI for better readability.

To more clarify, Input Mask make `QLineEdit`s to work in *overwrite* mode not *insert* mode. But setting a `QValidator` leaves `QLineEdit` working in *insert* mode untouched.

For example if you type `"AA3"`, GUI shows `"AA  3"` but `text()` method returns `AA3`. If you now move the cursor back to 3th position and type `"B"`, the GUI shows `"AAB 3"` (not `"AAB  3"`, because we are in *overwite* mode) and `text()` method returns `"AAB3"`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, `QRegExpValidator` is deprecated in Qt6, but there is a new `QRegularExpressionValidator`, so @Reimundo's example would be something like this:

```
QRegularExpression rgx("[a-zA-Z]{4}\\d{1,2}");
QValidator *comValidator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(rgx, this);
comLineEdit->setValidator(comValidator);
```